# Building a genus-$n$ torus from cubes

Tags: discrete-geometry, polyhedra, gt.geometric-topology, reference-request

I wonder if this has been studied:

> What is the fewest number of unit cubes
>   from which one can build an $n$-toroid?

The cubes must be glued face-to-face,
and the boundary of the resulting object should 
be topologically equivalent to an $n$-torus, by which I mean
a genus-$n$ handlebody in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (as per Kevin Walker's terminological correction).
For example, 8 cubes are needed to form a 1-toroid:

          
[image: CuboidTorus1]

And it seems that 13 cubes are needed for a 2-toroid:

          
[image: CuboidTorus2]

I know how intricate is the analogous question for minimizing the
number of triangles from which one can build a torus
(cf. Császár's Torus), but I am hoping that my much easier question
has an answer for arbitrary $n$.
Thanks for ideas and/or pointers!

**Addendum**. Here is Steve Huntsman's 20-cube candidate for genus-5:

          
[image: CuboidTorus5]

Comment: Visualizing this in my head, for n = 3, 4, 5, 6 the numbers appear to be 16, 19, 24, and 20. To see this (even if my mental picture turns out to be flawed), imagine bending your 2-torus, then adding 3 cubes to get a 3-torus, and the same again for a 4-torus. Adding one more cube can get a 6-torus (the 3x3x3 cube with face and body centers removed), whereas a 5-torus requires adding 5 cubes along the periphery of the 4-torus. OEIS comes up dry on the initial sequence 8, 13, 16, 19, 24, 20, though there are 4 matches for the first 4 terms.

Comment: Some terminological nitpicks: "n-torus" usually means "n-dimensional torus", not a genus n surface.  The standard term for what you're talking about is "genus n handlebody" (assuming that the 3-dimensional context has already been established).  Also, what exactly do you mean by "cuboid"?  The Wikipedia article lists two different definitions, and the answer to your question will depend on which definition you intend.  From your figures it appears that by "cuboid" you just mean "cube".

Comment: @Steve: Your 20-cube "6-torus" (the symmetric one) is actually a "5-torus", or rather a genus 5 handlebody.

Comment: @Kevin-Augh, you're right. I just drew a picture and saw how squashing the skeleton of a cube gives genus 5. 

Comment: There is a $2$-dimensional version of this question which is not trivial. 

Comment: @Kevin: Sorry for not knowing the standard terminology. By *cuboid* I mean "unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Wikipedia: "In the theory of surfaces the term $n$-torus has a different meaning." Thanks for these clarifications.

Comment: The "very porous" cube of side $2L+1$ has $4L^3+9L^2+6L+1$ cubes and genus $2L^3+3L^2$. This gives an asymptotic bound of $2n$ to get a genus-$n$ handlebody.

Comment: Presumably an approximately spherical object made of the same porous material would give a slightly better asymptotic bound.

Comment: I've now removed the misleading "cuboid" terminology.

Comment: Fixed one occurrence of "torus", changing it to "toroid".

Comment: But I think that occurrence was correct...

Comment: @Lee: Paul is correct, so I rolled back. Sorry for all this confusion!

Comment: I think Joseph's desired function should be monotonic in the genus n. One should be able to construct a genus n example by removing at most one cube (but not  just any cube) from a genus n+1 example. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.06

Comment: Here is an lower bound for each genus $n$. Consider a "general cuboid" $X$ meaning any finite union of unit cubes in the standard lattice. There is a cube $C \subset X$ and a corner $v \in C$ such that $v$ touches no other cubes in $X$; this follows by consideration of the convex hull of $X$. Removal of $C$ from the union of cubes forming $X$ produces another general cuboid $X'$. 

Comment: One gets an inequality of the Euler characteristic: $\chi(X) \ge \chi(X') - 6$; the worst case, when you get equality, occurs when $C$ is the center $1 \times 1 \times 1$ cube in a big $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube whose intersection with $X'$ are the $7$ corner cubes of the big cube that don't touch $v$. By stripping away cubes one at a time in this fashion one gets $\chi(X) \ge -6 C(X)$ where $C(X)$ is the number of cubes forming $X$. So if we started with a toroid $X$ we get $genus(X) = 1 - \chi(X) \le 1 + 6 C(X)$ and so $C_n \ge \frac{1}{6}(n-1)$.

Comment: Fiddling about with combinatorics, cubical homology, and the bound $F\ge 4g$ for a triangulation of a genus-$g$ surface, it should be possible to improve that bound to $C_n\ge g-\frac12$ (modulo correctness of my computations). I haven't been able to get any significant improvement from here..

Comment: A very porous approximation to a sphere is less efficient (fewer holes per cube) than a very porous cube. This may be easier to see in the $2$-dimensional version. 

Comment: @Lee Mosher: Stripping away cubes may not preserve the fact that the surface is a combinatorial manifold.

Comment: One should have that adding a cube adds at most one to the genus, so that it takes at least 15 + g cubes to get a figure with genus at least g when g > 3. This is because the surface of the figure is connected and (I believe but cannot yet prove) there is a cube which can be removed which changes the genus by at most 1.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.08

Comment: I don't see why the cube is a 5-genus, not 6-genus, torus..

Comment: @Campello: imagine stretching one side out and making the whole thing ``planar''.  Then one of the ``holes" is the exterior, and so does not count as a ``hole".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let $c(g)$ be the minimum number of cubes such that the boundary of some configuration of $c(g)$ cubes is a genus $g$ surface.  Then $c(g)/g \to 2$ as $g \to \infty$.

*Proof.* We write $\chi(X)$ for the compactly supported Euler characteristic
of $X$, i.e.,

$\chi(X) = \sum (-1)^i \dim H^i_c(X, \mathbb{Q})$.

Note this is not a homotopy invariant: the compactly supported Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $(-1)^n$.  It does however have the property that for reasonable finite disjoint union decompositions, $X = \coprod X_i$, we have $\chi(X) = \sum \chi(X_i)$.

Let $H_g$ be a closed genus $g$ handle-body.  Then $$\chi(H_g) = 1-g.$$

On the other hand, let $K$ be a configuration of cubes.  We write $K^0, K^1, K^2, K^3$ for the sets of vertices, edges, squares, and cubes, respectively, 
and $k^0, k^1, k^2, k^3$ for their cardinalities. Then

$$\chi(K) = k^0 - k^1 + k^2 - k^3$$

We will count $k^0, k^1, k^2, k^3$ by looking at the interior of the $2 \times 2$ cube around each vertex.  That is, abutting some vertex $v$, there is $1$ vertex, $6$ edges, $12$ faces, and $8$ cubes.  More to the point, each $i$-dimensional face abuts $2^i$ vertices.  We write $K_v$ to mean the configuration localized at $v$; we write $K^i_v$ for the set of $i$-dimensional faces which abut the vertex $v$, and $k^i_v$ for its cardinality.  Thus:

$$\chi(K) = \sum_{v \in \mathbb{Z}^3} \sum_{i=0}^3 (-2)^{-i} \cdot 
k^i_v $$

so we estimate

$$\frac{\chi(K)}{k^3} = \frac{\sum_{v \in \mathbb{Z}^3} \sum_{i=0}^3 (-2)^{-i} \cdot k^i_v }{\sum_{v \in \mathbb{Z}^3} 2^{-3} \cdot  k^3_v } \ge 
\min_{v \in \mathbb{Z}^3} \sum_i \frac{(-2)^{-i} \cdot k^i_v }{2^{-3} \cdot k^3_v }$$

The above inequality comes from the following fact: a (weighted) average is greater than the minimum term being averaged.  Thus for any $a_i, b_i$ with $b_i > 0$, we have

$$\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i} = \sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} \cdot \frac{b_i}{\sum b_i}
\ge \min_i \frac{a_i}{b_i}$$

Now let us analyze the possibilities for the right hand quantity

$$\tau(K_v) := \frac{8}{k_v^3} \cdot \left(k_v^0 - \frac{k_v^1}{2} + \frac{k_v^2}{4} - 
\frac{k_v^3}{8} \right)  $$

In fact, in the $2\times 2$ cube around a vertex, there are, up to symmetry, only 9 possible configurations of cubes whose boundary is (locally at that vertex) topologically a manifold: one each for every number of boxes other than 4, and for 4 boxes, the square, and the tripod configuration where, if say $v = (0,0,0)$, the cubes are the ones with most negative coordinates $(-1,-1,-1)$, $(-1, -1, 0)$, $(-1, 0, -1)$, and $(0, -1, -1)$.  Note that the neighborhood of every point in the interior of a very porous solid is a tripod configuration.

It remains to compute in each of these cases the above quantity.  For example, in the configuration $C_1$ when there is one cube, there is one vertex abutting the central one, three edges, three faces, and one cube.  Thus this contributes

$$ \tau(C_1) = \frac{8}{1} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{8}  \right) = 1$$

We tabulate the remaining cases:

$$ \tau(C_2) = \frac{8}{2}  \cdot \left(1 - \frac{4}{2} + \frac{5}{4} - \frac{2}{8}  \right) = 0$$

$$ \tau(C_3) = \frac{8}{3} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{5}{2} + \frac{7}{4} - \frac{3}{8}  \right) = -\frac{1}{3}$$

$$ \tau(C_4) = \frac{8}{4} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{5}{2} + \frac{8}{4} - \frac{4}{8}  \right) = 0$$

$$ \tau(C_4') = \frac{8}{4} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{6}{2} + \frac{9}{4} - \frac{4}{8}  \right) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ \tau(C_5) = \frac{8}{5} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{6}{2} + \frac{10}{4} - \frac{5}{8}  \right) = -\frac{1}{5}$$

$$ \tau(C_6) = \frac{8}{6} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{6}{2} + \frac{11}{4} - \frac{6}{8}  \right) = 0$$

$$ \tau(C_7) = \frac{8}{7} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{6}{2} + \frac{12}{4} - \frac{7}{8}  \right) = \frac{1}{7}$$

$$ \tau(C_8) = \frac{8}{8} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{6}{2} + \frac{12}{4} - \frac{8}{8}  \right) = 0$$

Here, $C_4'$ is the tripod configuration.  We conclude that

$$\frac{1-g(K)}{\# K^3} = \frac{\chi(K)}{\# K^3} \ge -\frac{1}{2}$$

hence $\# K^3 \ge 2g(K) - 2$.

On the other hand, for any family of configurations in which the fraction of $v$ with $K_v \sim C_4'$ -- i.e., the probability that (the neighborhood of a given cube is a very porous solid) -- tends to 1, the estimates above are sharp and $\# K^3 /g(K) \to 2$.

(An explicit calculation for the very porous cube appears in the comments above.) $\blacksquare$

Comment: By "$K_1$ lines" do you mean "$K_1$ edges"?

Comment: yeah, where an 'edge' is a length 1 interval.  I changed it.

Comment: Impressive analysis! Kudos!